# How to troubleshoot slow connection issues from SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017, windows-server

I right click on a server in the `Registered Servers` pane and select `New Query`.  Sometimes (like 1 out of 3), it will just hang for 5-15 seconds with the Connect dialog (below).  Other times, it connects immediately.

I thought this may have been a network issue, so I have `ping` running indefinitely just for comparison and the ping times are steady.  So it's not a network issue.  The servers themselves are not CPU pegged by any stretch of imagination.

This problem occurs with all the SQL corporate boxes that I connect to during the day.

All the SQL Server boxes are v2017, Enterprise edition, running on Windows 2016, which is running in a VMWare VM.  I am using SSMS 17.9.1. I am also running the Redgate SQL Prompt add-on v8.0.7.1917 in SSMS, but (from my testing) it seem to have any bearing on the connection times.

How do I troubleshoot this issue?

[image]

Comment: Also try using the latest 18.x SSMS version

Comment: @LowlyDBA I have to walk back my earlier statement about the success (and delete the comment).  After a period of fast access, the problem has returned.  DNS appears not to be the issue.

Comment: How about using a SQL Login for a period of time and see if the problem occurs. If it doesn't, then it is likely authentication issues with the domain controlled. If it does, then probably a networking issue, along the lines that LowlyDBA linked to.